# MySQL query cannot find large alphanumeric values? - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some PHP that needs to connect to my mySQL database and return the email that corresponds to a transaction_id.  The following code connects to the database fine but when I try to query the table with `...WHERE transction_id='large value'` (see code below) nothing returns.  Do I need to do something different to use the WHERE clause with large values that are a mix of numbers, letters and upper/lower case?  The large value comes in as the "session" parameter but I have written in the actual value to show you what this looks like.

Thanks,

```
public function readEmailFromDB ( $session ) {


$con=mysqli_connect("host", "username", "pass", "db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = ("SELECT email AS mailStuff FROM hfw_tbb_booking WHERE transaction_id='c2VhbmFhcm9uMTAwQGdtYWlsLmNvbToyMDEzLTExLTI5OjM3ODAwOjA6MToxMzg1NTM2NzQw'");

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

     echo $result->fetch_object()->mailStuff;

     $finalResult = $result->fetch_object()->mailStuff;
```

Comment: i dont think so. It should work. What is the data type of transaction_id. (it should not be integer).

Comment: You don't need to do anything special except check for typos

Comment: transaction_id is text

Comment: Isn't using text a bit overkill for your transaction id? Surely a varchar would be better

Comment: can you run your sql query directly in database and check any output comes or not.

Comment: Yes the exact same query works perfect in database.  With the exact output I expect.

Comment: Also tried varchar but nothing :(

Comment: You might be connecting to the wrong database. Happened to me all too many times.

Comment: No because other queries will work.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps some leading and trailing whitespaces , try `like`

```
SELECT email AS mailStuff FROM hfw_tbb_booking WHERE transaction_id LIKE '%c2VhbmFhcm9uMTAwQGdtYWlsLmNvbToyMDEzLTExLTI5OjM3ODAwOjA6MToxMzg1NTM2NzQw%'
```

or use

```
LTRIM / RTRIM
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that too and I tried this suggestion but no difference.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to do something different to use the WHERE clause with large values that are a mix of numbers, letters and upper/lower case?

No.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the echo statement.  This was "redefining" the $result variable.